# How can I change the position of the points in a Polygon2D node with a line of code?

Tags: godot, godot4

There doesn't seem to be any clear info elsewhere online on this topic. What I want to do is write a line of code to specify the location of a specific point in the polygon. How is this done?

I tried this:

```
var newPoly = Polygon2D.new()
newPoly.polygon = [[0,0],[100,100],[400,500]]
```

But it has no effect on the polygon node itself.

Comment: That code is creating a new `Polygon2D` (i.e. a new `Node`), is that what you want?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

The `polygon` property is a `PackedVector2Array`, that is a compact in memory array of `Vector2D`.

While Godot will try to convert any `Array` to `PackedVector2Array` when you assign it, Godot will not covert `Array` to `Vector2D`.

Thus, instead of this:

```
newPoly.polygon = [[0,0],[100,100],[400,500]]
```

You need to do this:

```
newPoly.polygon = [Vector2(0,0),Vector2(100,100),Vector2(400,500)]
```

---

By the way, there Godot is converting from `int` to `float`, you can write float literals if you want (e.g. `0.0` instead of `0`). And if you want to be explicit about the conversion to `PackedVector2Array`, you can pass the array to `PackedVector2Array(...)`. For example:

```
newPoly.polygon = PackedVector2Array(
    [
        Vector2(0.0, 0.0),
        Vector2(100.0, 100.0),
        Vector2(400.0, 500.0)
    ]
)
```